# How to initialize objects with unknown arguments?

Tags: php, oop, class-design

I'm trying to make a class which has methods called using PHP's `__call()` magic method. This magic method will then be initializing another object like this :

```
public function  __call($function, $arguments) {

    /* Only allow function beginning with 'add' */
    if ( ! preg_match('/^add/', $function) ) {
        trigger_error('Call to undefined method ' . __CLASS__ . '::' . $function, E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $class = 'NamodgField_' . substr($function, 3); /* Ex: $function = addTextField() => $class = NamodgField_TextField */

    /* This doesn't work! Because $class is not an object yet */
    call_user_func_array( array(new $class, '__construct'), $arguments);
}
```

The last line of that code is totally worng! I'm just trying to make clear what I want to do.

I want to be able to pass the `$arguments` when initializing a new object, one after the other, So that each child class could define it's necessary arguments.

I figured a solution using `eval()` , but I really don't like it.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('a');
$object = $class->newInstanceArgs(array(1, 2, 3));

class a
{
    public function __construct($b, $c, $d)
    {
        var_dump($b, $c, $d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you so much ^^